# View images fit to width in Image Viewer

Tags: eog

How can I make the Image viewer fit all images to width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install the [eog-plugins](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eog-plugins&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install eog-plugins
   ```
2. Open Image Viewer and navigate to *Edit* ➜ *Preferences* ➜ *Plugins* and check the *Zoom to fit image width* plugin:

   [image: eog preferences window]
3. Restart Image Viewer for the change to take effect.

Comment: Sigh, so I need to install yet another extra `deb`...

Comment: this doesn't work for me on ubuntu 13.04, image viewer 3.6.2

Comment: Hrm, there's no setting available to make "fit to width" the default `eog-plugins-3.16.2` :/

Comment: Can't see any ability to fit width after installation `eog-plugins` on my Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Installing all plugins isn't required, `eog-plugin-fit-to-width` is already enough.