# How to show images in normal size by default with Image Viewer

Tags: 13.04, image-viewers

By default when I open an image it fits to the window size (scaled down). I have to hit  the button **Show the image at its normal size** every time when I go to the Next/Previous image or open a new image.

I tried [View images fit to width in Image Viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58007/view-images-fit-to-width-in-image-viewer), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I think that it is probably just impossible. Image Viewer is a pretty simple app generally.

What I would recommend is installing Gthumb, which has more functions, including the one you need.

```
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

There you can find this option in **Preferences > Viewer** tab I guess.

I know that this isn't the exact answer you're looking for, but I hope that it will help anyway.

Comment: I'm not interested in using another Image app

Comment: Thanks @kcpr. Your suggestion worked: Ubuntu 15.10, gThumb 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I can come up with is the [qiv image viewer](http://spiegl.de/qiv/)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This just needs the maintainer of **Eye of GNOME** (eog) to create a plugins file for version **3.6.2**.

There is one for 3.6.1, and copying it (with only a minor change) should solve this. Within the download file (.zip or .tar.gz) the file '**/eog-plugins/config.ac**' needs line 5 changed: from **`[3.6.1]`** to **`[3.6.2]`**. *The remaining code seems to all be **>= 3.5.5** compatible.*

This should be raised as a bug/feature ..